# Алгоритм рисования дерева каталогов

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я пытался написать аналог DOSовской утилиты tree на питоне. Это которая рисует дерево каталогов. Вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все чего я смог добиться, это вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, некоторые пути, которые помечены красным, я не могу придумать как нарисовать. Вернее мысли есть, даже что-то получалось, но там такой треш в скрипте творился что я сам с трудом понимал как оно работает. Мне кажется, я изначально неверно подошел к решению задачи. Поэтому прошу помощи более умных людей.
Я знаю про os.system('tree'). Но смысл не в результате, а в процессе.

```
import os


def tree(my_path='.'):

    print(my_path)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(my_path):
        deep = path.replace(my_path, '').count(os.sep)
        space = '   ' * (deep - 1)
        if deep == 1:
            print('{}|__{}'.format(space, os.path.basename(path)))
        elif deep > 1:
            print('|{}|__{}'.format(space, os.path.basename(path)))


tree()
```

Comment: кодом нe помогу, но идeя вот какая - для папки сначала хранить список всeх подкаталогов, т.e а b c и т.д. Потом идeм циклично вниз, eсли у каталога eсть рeбeнок - заходим в нeго и парсим дальшe, eсли нeт - выводим для нeго соотвeтствуюeщee колличeство палок(их надо будeт запоминать на каждом шагe и при пeчати отнимать от этого числа столько, сколько шагов назад надо сдeлать до пeрвого каталога)

Comment: в общeм получится интeрeсный такой рeкурсивный алгоритм построeния бинарного дeрeва - графа. можeт завтра присоeдинюсь

Comment: Она даже не рекурсивная... Не, так не пойдёт. Делай рекурсию и читай на элемент вперёд перед рекурсивным вызовом.

Comment: @Qwertiy рeкурсивно  имeл в виду провeрку на наличиe дeтeй

Comment: @finally, я к автору обращался)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
from pathlib import Path

fork_string   = '├──'
corner_string = '└──'
wall_string   = '│  '
space_string  = '   '

def drawtree(path, seen, head='', tail=''):
    if path.is_dir() and path.resolve() not in seen:
        yield head + path.name
        seen.add(path.resolve()) # на случай зацикленных ссылок
        entries = sorted(filter(Path.is_dir, path.iterdir()))

        for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
            if i < len(entries) - 1:
                yield from drawtree(entry, seen, tail + fork_string, tail + wall_string)
            else:
                yield from drawtree(entry, seen, tail + corner_string, tail + space_string)

def tree(my_path='.'):
    for line in drawtree(Path(my_path), set()):
        print(line)

tree('root')
```

```
root
├──Folder
│  ├──a
│  │  ├──aa
│  │  ├──ab
│  │  │  └──aab
│  │  └──ac
│  ├──b
│  └──c
│     └──cc
│        ├──ccc
│        └──cce
└──something
```

Меньше функционала, без проверок, но более кратко и наглядно

```
from pathlib import Path

def tree(path='.', head='', tail=''):
    path = Path(path)

    if path.is_dir():
        print(head + path.name)
        entries = sorted(filter(Path.is_dir, path.iterdir()))

        for i, entry in enumerate(entries):
            if i < len(entries) - 1:
                tree(entry, tail + '├──', tail + '│  ')
            else:
                tree(entry, tail + '└──', tail + '   ')

tree('root')
```

Comment: Cпасибо всем откликнувшимся! #extrn отдельное спасибо.

Comment: Теперь появилась мысль написать эмулятор командной строки ДОС на питоне... Назову PythDOS.

Comment: Почему-то этот скрипт печатает и файлы тоже. Не могу понять, вроде проверка же if path.is_dir() есть.

Comment: @Keymaster честно сказать, я забыл как работает tree, думал и файлы выводить нужно :) Исправил, а также добавил упрощенный вариант.

Comment: Спасибо большое!