# Команда Linux для вывода структуры каталогов в виде дерева

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

Есть ли какая-либо команда Linux, которую я могу вызвать из скрипта Bash, который напечатает структуру каталогов в виде дерева, например:

```
dir1
  aa.txt
  bb.txt
dir2
  dir3
...
```

Comment: Возможно программа `tree` должна помочь в вашей задаче

Comment: bash: tree: command not found

Comment: @eri ее поставить надо.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3455625/linux-command-to-print-directory-structure-in-the-form-of-a-tree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрипт Bash с использованием программы `tree` для создания файла Markdown в корне репозитория со ссылками на его объекты. Полученный файл удобно использовать для навигации по репозиторию в вёб-интерфейсе.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Построение дерева каталогов со ссылками."
{
  echo "## Дерево каталогов"
  echo
  echo "<pre>"
  tree -nvf --dirsfirst -I "*.gem|*.lock|*.zip|_site*" --noreport
  echo "</pre>"
} >DIRECTORY-TREE.md
sed -i -e "s/\xC2\xA0/ /g" -e "s/   /  /g" -e "s/──/─/g" DIRECTORY-TREE.md
find . -mindepth 1 -type f,d | sort -r | while read -r file; do
  echo "Обработка: \\$file >> ${file#*/} >> ${file##*/}"
  sed -i "s|\\$file|<a href='${file#*/}'>${file##*/}<\/a>|g" DIRECTORY-TREE.md
done
```

---

| Скриншот | Описание алгоритма |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Дерево каталогов 1] | 1. Выполняем программу `tree` и получаем дерево каталогов в текстовом виде, где для каждого файла указываем полный префикс пути Linux от корня репозитория. Папки выводим перед файлами и применяем буквенно-цифровую сортировку. Исключаем файлы и папки, которых не должно быть в репозитории. Полученное дерево помещаем в блок `<pre>` и добавляем заголовок. |
| [image: Дерево каталогов 2] | 2. Для красоты, веточки-рамки у дерева box-drawing делаем короче. Для замены подстрок используем программу `sed` и регулярные выражения. Неразрывные пробелы `U+00A0` заменяем на обычные пробелы. Пошагово формируем файл `DIRECTORY-TREE.md`. |
| [image: Дерево каталогов 3] | 3. Далее выполняем программу `find` и получаем список файлов и каталогов Linux, сортируем этот список в обратном порядке от самого длинного пути до самого короткого, т. е. вложенные файлы будут перед их каталогами, чтобы не получилось заменить только часть пути. Затем обходим отсортированный список и заменяем в полученном дереве относительный путь Linux на относительную ссылку HTTP в теге `<a>` и именем файла в представлении ссылки. |
| [image: Дерево каталогов 4] | 4. Получаем файл `DIRECTORY-TREE.md` для вёб-интерфейса репозитория — Markdown преобразованный в HTML. |

Comment: [Алгоритм рисования дерева каталогов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1065735) — python, а мне нужен bash.